# git push uses wrong path to ssh key

Tags: git, ssh, path, repository, git-push

I've set up a repository in Git and when I try to push something with `git push -u origin master` it says:

> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

I have the feeling git tries to use the rsa-key from `/u/path/.ssh/id_rsa_pub/` (which doesn't exist anymore) instead of `/c/path/.ssh/id_rsa_pub/`.

How do I change the path, that's used to check if the public key is valid.

Maybe something else is the problem.

(The git repository knows my public-key)

Comment: In case you are pushing to `gitlab.com`, I often get these kind of errors. It goes back to normal after a while.

Comment: To push you use your private key, and the server checks it against your public key.

Comment: You can just create custom path to your private key. Are you in Linux or which environment?

Comment: One way to do is to set the customer path and move your private SSH key.

something like this. `ssh-add <path_of_your_ssh_key>`